# How to display properties of child classes from ObserveableCollection of base class?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm building a WPF application that's just a UI for a team member to edit an xml. My view model setup was working out decently until I ran into this problem.

Let's say I have a model "Animal" with "Dog" and "Bird" inheriting from it.

In my viewmodel, I have property

```
public ObservableCollection<AnimalViewModel> Animals {get; set;}
```

In my view, I display each animal in a listview, but for birds, I want there to be a checkbox for "CanFly" (penguins and whatnot). How could I set up my viewmodel and binding to do this?

Below is an example of my current setup.

```
//MODELS
public class Animal
{
    public string Name;
}

public class Dog:Animal
{
    public string Breed;
}

public class Bird:Animal
{
    public bool CanFly;
}

//VIEWMODELS
//PropertyChanged.Fody nuget package
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class BaseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };
}

public class AnimalDataVM:BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<AnimalVM> Animals{get;set;}
}

public class AnimalVM
{
    private Animal animal;
    public AnimalVM(Animal _animal)
    {
        animal = _animal;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return animal.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            animal.Name = value;
        }
    }
}

public class BirdVM
{
    private Bird bird;
    public BirdVM(Bird _bird)
    {
        bird = _bird;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return bird.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            bird.Name = value;
        }
    }

    public bool CanFly
    {
        get
        {
            return bird.CanFly;
        }
        set
        {
            bird.CanFly = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome.  Your question appears to be too broad and if so sadly off-topic for SO.  Any other code to show?  [ask].  Good luck good sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option would be to use `DataTemplate`. But that require you to have different classes in your `ViewModel`. Yet it's very efficient and easy to implement:

```
<ListView Name="MyListview">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AnimalViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="Animal"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DogViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="Dog"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BirdViewModel}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="Can fly"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Bird"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

If you cannot have different type in your `ViewModel`, then you should use `Style` `DataTrigger` and your classes properties:

```
<ListView Name="MyListview">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="Can fly">
                    <CheckBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBird}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </CheckBox.Style>
                </CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="Anything"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: The second solution would probably work fine if I was using a partial class right? I'm trying to work with inheritance specifically. I updated the OP to include some more information if that helps.

Comment: Yes. Regarding your update, the `DataTemplate` seems to be the best practice for me. The only problem would be the common code between the different templates that we don't want to duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I think maybe I'm misunderstanding something though. If I have an ObserveableCollection<Animal>, how would a data template know which type to use? It would just always use Animal right? Or am I tackling this problem completley wrong?

Comment: Actually the `DataTemplate` support polymorphism very well. In simplier words, to resolve the type it uses the *Instantiation* type, and not the *Declaration* type. If it cannot resolve/recognize the current type, it will loop through the different base classes.

Comment: Oh wow! That sounds fantastic! I'll give it a go tomorrow and mark this as answered if it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Yup, that seemed to do the trick. My data is stored in a model list of Animals, so I had to manually cast them to viewmodel versions of themselves. I'm not too fond of that, but that's for another day. Thanks again!